# Intent fails because of Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

What I have: I have a RecyclerView with images of bars, coffee shops. etc

What I want: That when you click on one of these images I show you the info of the selected place, but on the moment that you click the selected image the app crashes and shows this error "Attempt to invoke virtual method '`java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()`' on a null object reference" on the line where i create the Intent. I have already looked for this error but i am doing everything as they say

My question: How do I fix this? Please, I would really appreciate the examples with code, i am not good at programming yet, thanks in advance

My java class

```
    public class foodAndGo extends AppCompatActivity {
    ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares;
    RecyclerView recyclerview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_food_and_go);

       listalugares = new ArrayList<ClaseNueva>();
       recyclerview = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.RecyclerID);
       recyclerview.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

       llenarLugares();

       AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(foodAndGo.this, listalugares);
       recyclerview.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private void llenarLugares() {
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Restaurantes", R.drawable.carnemejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Bares", R.drawable.beers));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Cafeterías", R.drawable.desayunosmejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Pizzerías", R.drawable.pizzaamejor));
        listalugares.add(new ClaseNueva("Favoritos", R.drawable.favoritosmejo));

    }
}
```

My Adapter

```
    public class AdapterDatos extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterDatos.ViewHolder> {


    ArrayList<ClaseNueva>listalugares;
    Context context;

    public AdapterDatos(foodAndGo foodAndGo, ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listalugares = listalugares;
    }


    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {//quizas poner esto en estatic
        TextView etiNombre;
        ImageView foto;

//        Context context;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
//            context = itemView.getContext();

            etiNombre = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idNombre);
            foto = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.idImagen);
        }
        void setOnClickListeners(){
            foto.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
//            switch (v.getId()){
//                case R.id.idImagen:
//                    Intent intent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
//                    context.startActivity(intent);
//                    break;
//            }

        }
    }


    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list,null,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.etiNombre.setText(listalugares.get(position).getNombre());
        holder.foto.setImageResource(listalugares.get(position).getFoto());

//        holder.setOnClickListeners();
       if (position == 0){
           holder.foto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
               public void onClick(View v) {
                   Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, MapsActivity.class);
                   context.startActivity(myIntent);
               }
           });
       }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listalugares.size();
    }

}
```

Comment: you are doing wron here ! public AdapterDatos(foodAndGo foodAndGo, ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listalugares = listalugares;
    }

Comment: it's public AdapterDatos(Context context, ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares) { this.context = context; this.listalugares = listalugares; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forget to pass context from activity !

```
AdapterDatos adapter = new AdapterDatos(foodAndGo.this,listalugares);
```

Receive context in Adapter :-

```
public AdapterDatos(Context context , ArrayList<ClaseNueva> listalugares) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listalugares = listalugares;
    }
```

I hope this help you!

Comment: It keeps crashing, i already added, foodAndgo.this as second parameter, i even actualized my question with the answer you gave me

Comment: OMG!! I am so stupid, i was adding as second parameter foodAndGo.this to AdapterDatos. Thank you so much my friend

Comment: No problem friend it happens !Your are going good , All the best :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to fetch the context in adapter. I've another solution for. You can get context using the code below

```
context = holder.foto.getContext();
```

So, we will get context from **foto** component in adapter. Lets try!

**UPDATE**

You need to put that code in onBindViewHolder and above

```
if (position == 0){
```